# Combinatorics Terminology: Finite Sequence of Symbols Modulo Reversal

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Simple question, hard to Google:

What do we call the combinatorial species that associates a set of symbols with linear configuration or chain of symbols without a designated first or last symbol?  Or the combinatorial species of finite sequences modulo identification under reversal?

Edit: a linear necklace?  A bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29.

In short:
A finite sequence up to rotational invariance is called "necklace". A finite sequence up to rotation and reflection is called a "bracelet".